# Unexpected behavior when using multiple MeshFunctions; definitions not kept isolated from each other

Tags: plotting

I was trying to devise an answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125234/9490) that relied entirely on `MeshFunctions` to do all the work, but I ran into some unexpected behavior.

Consider two simple `MeshFunctions` and how they behave separately:

```
func1 = If[#1 > 0, #1 + #2] &;
func2 = If[#2 < 0, #1] &;
RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 < 3, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
   MeshFunctions -> {#},
   Mesh -> {Range[-1, 4, .5]},
   PlotPoints -> 100] & /@ {func1, func2}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

My understanding is that I should be able to add both of these functions together, perhaps with different styles via

```
RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 < 3, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
 MeshFunctions -> {func1, func2},
 Mesh -> {Range[-1, 4, .5], Range[-1, 4, .5]},
 MeshStyle -> {{Red}, {Blue}},
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But it didn't work; the conditional statement from `func1` is used when applying `func2`.  If I remove the `If` statements, using `MeshFunctions -> {#1 + #2 &, #1 &}` then it works just fine.

Is this in the documentation somewhere?

Comment: Perhaps "The Subscript[m, i] should normally be chosen to be continuous monotonic functions." ("Details", docs for `MeshFunctions`)  But it's a bit vague about what happens when you use functions that are undefined (or return `Null`) over part of the plot domain.

Comment: @MichaelE2 That sounds about right, probably it